# C++ does not compile (link?) in XCode 4.2

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, osx-lion, objective-c++

I have a very small program in Xcode only displaying a label and changing the text of the label in the viewWillAppear method. The label.text should come from a C++ library with a function like this:

```
int getNumber(){
    return 42;
}
```

The problem is, that including the class with *#import "TestLibMain.h"* in my *.mm(!) class and using the function with

```
TestLibMain *tlb = new TestLibMain();
int myInt = tlb->getNumber();
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myInt];
```

doesn't invoke a compiler error, but a linker error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "TestLibMain::getNumber()", referenced from:
   -[tbViewController buttonPressed:] in tbViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

My impression is, that the cpp-class has not been compiled.

I tried a lot of things around, but somewhere it's hanging. It's all in the same directory, I use the .mm extension, everything fine, but always this linker error. Getting crazy :-)

Mac OS X Lion, XCode 4.2

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the library built for 32-bit or 64-bit architecture?

Comment: Interesting question. My hope was that the library "TestLibMain" which contains the function getNumber() is automatically created during compilation of the Xcode-project. So I do not have any pre-compiled library. Am I wrong in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int getNumber() {
    return 42;
}
```

in a `.cpp` or `.mm` defines `getNumber()` as a free function.  This:

```
int TestLibMain::getNumber() {
    return 42;
}
```

defines `getNumber()` as a member of `TestLibMain`.

Comment: Yeah. You won the price, thanx a lot :-)